# Django Model: What is a efficient way to list Foreign Key?

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-models

I have three models below. I omit some irrelative fields.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Match(models.Model):
    home = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    away = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    home_players = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    away_players = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

`home_players` and `away_players` have the type of player id list, such as [1,2,3,...,15].

I want to know better ways like using Foreign Key List.
Because, I have some troubles in manually inserting players IDs  at **Django Admin Page**. It takes much time finding player name in `Player()` and matching player's ID. I guess the task would be easier if I can assign a certain relationship between `Player()` and `Team()`.

Comment: You've already assigned a relationship between team and players but your models don't represent that, so yes you should have an fk to a team on the player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) relationship.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

```
class Match(models.Model):
    home = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    away = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    home_players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)
    away_players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)
```

Comment: Thank you, C14L. Your code work correctly. To add one more question.... Is there a constraint option to let an instance of `Player()` belong to one `Team()`?

Comment: That could be a ForeignKey on your Player model: `team =  models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='players')`. Then [in `Match.clean()` check](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) that each player is playing on their own team.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It was very helpful. @C14L